# Can't delete files or folders on partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, delete

I have an NTFS partition. The idea is I can use this for data on either Ubuntu Mate or Windows 10 dual boot. It worked fine when I first installed Mate, but recently I no longer have the delete option when I right-click on a file or folder. The delete key does nothing. I also can't paste into the partition (Paste greyed out). It's as if the whole partition is read-only.
In Gparted, the partition is marked with a key. Does this mean anything?
I'm not aware of having changed anything, however, Windows recently did a big update - have they hijacked my drive?

I've read related posts, but people speak of returned errors - I have no errors, just nothing happens. Also, suggested solutions seem far too technical for what must surely be a simple tick-a-box fix!

Please note - for me the Terminal is where I get off a train and Sudo sounds like a Japanese noodle dish. ;) GUI's preferred if possible! Thanks for your patient help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, it's probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

## in Windows

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: Thanks hugely heynnema for your wonderfully easy to follow and 100% effective reply!  The Windows update had turned fast-startup back on and checkdisk found a few anomalies too. Now everything's back up and running.  Thanks again.